# Coroutine to support AWS calls seemingly not working as expected

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am building a service that needs to call AWS SageMaker endpoint to get forecast result. As there are lots of requests, I am exploring Coroutine to parallelize the calls as I am using Kotlin. However, I am new to Coroutines and the result seems to be a little inconsistent with [Coroutines official guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-and-channels.html).

The code below shows the logic. I have a list of features/inputs and I partition them into several partitions, with each partition sent to SageMaker supported by a Coroutine using `async`. From my understanding, Coroutines are light weight and the thread might change for the same coroutine after a suspend function call. However, the log for the implementation below show the thread for the Coroutine is always the same unless I uncomment `delay(100)` in the suspend function.

Any idea why? My concern is that the call to AWS SageMaker is always blocking the thread and Coroutine.

```
   fun forecastBatch(
        features: Set<String>
    ): Map<String, float> {
        val partitions: List<List<String>> = features.chunked(MAX_BATCH_SIZE)
        val result: MutableMap<String, float> = mutableMapOf()
        runBlocking {
            val deferreds = partitions.mapIndexed { idx, partition ->
                CoroutineName("Coroutine-${idx}")
                    log.info("${Thread.currentThread().name} Coroutines:  ${currentCoroutineContext()[CoroutineName]} for Sending Request ${idx}X")
                    val batchRequest = partition.joinToString("\n")

                    val forecastResult = invokeEndpoint(batchRequest)
                    
                    log.info("${Thread.currentThread().name} Coroutines:  ${currentCoroutineContext()[CoroutineName]}  Receiving Request ${idx}X")

                    // ...
                    // Build Response
                }
            }
            deferreds.awaitAll().forEach{
                result += it
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    suspend fun invokeEndpoint(input: String): String {
        // Build Request
        // ...        

        val result: InvokeEndpointResponse = sageMakerRuntimeClient.invokeEndpoint(request)
        
        // If the next line is uncommented, the thread will change for the same coroutine
        // delay(100)
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `sageMakerRuntimeClient.invokeEndpoint()` is not a suspend function, there is no suspension point in your `invokeEndpoint()` function, so it behaves just like normal blocking function. You can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) to convert traditional blocking function or callback style async function to kotlin stlye suspend function.

```kotlin
suspend fun invokeEndpoint(input:String) = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    // Build Request
    // ...  
    val result: InvokeEndpointResponse = sageMakerRuntimeClient.invokeEndpoint(request)
    continuation.resume(result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction! I followed your example and made the change. However, I didn't see the suspend function returned back. The 2nd `log.info` after invokeEndpoint was never executed. Any idea why this happened?